# Labeling large set of paired training data

Tags: python, pandas, labeling

I'm training a model to determine if two people are the same. The model should take in two people(represented as dataframe rows)

I'm trying to label paired data of
the form

```
Id  | age    | gender| occupation  | region | height | weight(kg)
100 | 16     | 0     | "plumber"   | na     | 169    | 20
300 | 50     | 1     | na          | africa | 12     | 90
```

```
Id  | age    | gender| occupation  | region | height | weight(kg)
100 | 16     | 0     | "plumber"   | na     | 169    | 20
700 | 100    | 0     | na          | africa | 12     | 90
```

Each of these pairs is sent to separate csv files for labeling, since I want to train a classifier that takes in pairs of people rows, and labels them as duplicates or not.

As you can see, if I have only 10 people, this could quickly get out of hand. 10 C 2 = 45 pairs. Any ideas, on how to make labeling the data easier?

I've thought about doing this in excel, but I feel like opening this many excel files is sure to create issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured it out, I just need to pair the rows in excel,
ie row1 features, row2 features, label.
It is pretty annoying to read the features horizontally, but if I use an external monitor or 2 it isn't terrible.

Answer (score 0):

- Sort the data frame **O(N*log(N))**
- Check to see whether adjacent rows are equal  **O(N)**

To do something with adjacent rows, simply `shift` the column one position; compare each row to the original.